# Verifying and Publishing Child Contract in Ethereum

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have a parent contract with the address 0x292BB3b1F6f1D008f9817Ec8345a64a20478200B that creates a child contract with the address 0x7106efec45e26a72b4735108eb00fed6da60a70f. However, I'm facing difficulties in verifying and publishing the child contract on the Ethereum blockchain.

The parent contract's Deploy() function creates a new instance of the child contract (MMYEscrow) and assigns it to the caller's address as an escrow account. The address of the deployed child contract is stored in a mapping called Escrows, with the caller's address as the key. Additionally, the relationship between the child contract address and the escrow owner is stored in the EscrowsToOwners mapping, and the escrow owner's address is added to an array called EscrowOwnerArray.

Here is the code snippet for the Deploy() function:

```
function Deploy() external nonReentrant returns (address Address) {
    address payable _EscrowOwner = payable(msg.sender);
    require(Escrows[msg.sender] == address(0), "Can only have 1 Escrow at a time, close other Escrow before creating a new one!");
    MMYEscrow NewEscrow = new MMYEscrow(_EscrowOwner);
    Address = address(NewEscrow);
    require(Address != address(0), "Deploy Escrow failed!");
    emit DeployedEscrow(Address, _EscrowOwner);
    Escrows[_EscrowOwner] = Address;
    EscrowsToOwners[Address] = _EscrowOwner;
    EscrowOwnerArray.push(_EscrowOwner);
}
```

The parent contract's Deploy() function successfully creates a new instance of the child contract (MMYEscrow) with the escrow owner's address. However, when I tried to verify the child contract, I encountered the following error:

Compiler debug log:
Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI
Found the following ContractName(s) in source code: DeployEscrow, IERC20, IMMYDeployEscrow, IMMYEligible, IMMYEscrow, IMMYRewardRouter, IPeripheryPayments, IPriceConsumerV3, ISwapRouter, IWFTM, MMYEscrow, ReentrancyGuard
But we were unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2)
For troubleshooting, you can try compiling your source code with the Remix - Solidity IDE and check for exceptions

Compiler Version: v0.8.17+commit.8df45f5f
Optimization Enabled: True
Runs: 200

ByteCode (what we are looking for):
60e0604052600280546001600160a01...

```
vs what we got -
```

We tried looking for a match from the list of compiled contract bytecode outputs (as listed below), but were unable to find an exact match.

```
DeployEscrow
60a06040526002805460ff60a01b1916600160a...

MMYEscrow
60e0604052600280546001600160a01b0...
```

I have also tried compiling the source code with the Remix - Solidity IDE, but I didn't encounter any exceptions.

What steps should I take to successfully verify and publish the child contract on the Ethereum blockchain? I want to ensure that the child contract's source code, bytecode, and contract address are publicly accessible and verifiable.